# I keep getting an error in my shiny app for linear regression?

Tags: shiny, linear-regression

I'm trying to create a shiny app and I can't seem to find the error in my code.

I keep getting this error here:

Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

I'm am also unsure as to what the inputs should be.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Linear Regression Shiny App"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h1("Linear Regression"),

            p("Select inputs for the Response
       Variable"),
            selectInput("ResVar",
                        "Response Variables:",
                        c("","","")
            ),

            p("Select inputs for the Predictor
       Variable"),
            selectInput("PreVar",
                       "Predictor Variables:",
                        c("","","")
            ),

            actionButton("goButton","Go!"),
            plotOutput("distPlot")),

        mainPanel = 
            verbatimTextOutput("ResVarPrint"),
        verbatimTextOutput("PreVarPrint")
    ))


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(ResVar,PreVar) {

    lm1 <- reactive({reformulate((input$ResVar),(input$PreVar))})

    output$ResPrint <- renderPrint({input$ResVar})
    output$PrePrint <- renderPrint({input$PreVar})
    output$RegSum <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})


}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The answer below addresses your question about the error you're seeing, but can you edit your question to provide more detail about what you mean by "unsure what the inputs should be"? That will help others give you a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You had misplaced some parenthesis near the end of you UI code, and tried to use `mainPanel=` instead of the proper `mainPanel(`. The UI code below addresses the error and gets your app to load.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Linear Regression Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("Linear Regression"),

      p("Select inputs for the Response
        Variable"),
      selectInput("ResVar",
                  "Response Variables:",
                  c("","","")
      ),

      p("Select inputs for the Predictor
        Variable"),
      selectInput("PreVar",
                  "Predictor Variables:",
                  c("","","")
      ),

      actionButton("goButton","Go!"),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("ResVarPrint"),
      verbatimTextOutput("PreVarPrint")
      )
  )
)
```

However, you may want to consider whether you actually want your `plotOutput` in the sidebar or whether you want it in the main panel, in which case you'll need to move it down.